# is it possible to figure out if there is enough memory available before creating a huge bitmap?

Tags: .net

sometime, i can create a 10000x10000 bitmap, sometime i can't

depending on how much available physical RAM is free

I would like to know if there a way to figure out before the process start if there enough memory or not

Comment: You don't list any particular O/S, but you're probably running on something with virtual memory.  Just checking the instantaneous free physical memory doesn't mean much.  A substantial amount may be used as cache and available on demand.  Additional memory may be made available by outpaging other processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the current process:

```
Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

And then use this to get the private memory usage:

```
proc.PrivateMemorySize64;
```

You could also do this (using System.Diagnostics.PerformaceCounter):

```
protected PerformanceCounter ramCounter; 
ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
var freeRAMInMB = ramCounter.NextValue();
```

The above would get the the amount of free RAM in MB...